# Smarty 3: Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Airmail/Form/Airmail/Settings.tpl' in 'file:CRM/Form/default.tpl'

Tags: extension, smarty, smarty3

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.69.2, PHP 7.4, **Smarty 3**.

After `civix upgrade`  run on some extensions (Airmail, Sendgrid) got two identical messages on the respective Settings URL/page:

```
Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Sendgrid/Form/SendGrid.tpl' in 'file:CRM/Form/default.tpl'

Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Airmail/Form/Airmail/Settings.tpl' in 'file:CRM/Form/default.tpl'
```

Smarty 2 works as expected.